# Can't return output of closure using graph api

Tags: ios, swift, facebook-graph-api

If I call this method to obtain a Facebook profile picture it does not work, response gets printed with the data but when I return it its nil, can anyone help?

```
func getProfilePicture() -> NSData?{
    var response:NSData?

    let graphRequest : FBSDKGraphRequest = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: ["fields":"picture.type(large)"])
    graphRequest.startWithCompletionHandler({ (connection, result, error) -> Void in

        if error != nil {
            print("login error: \(error!.localizedDescription)")
            return
        }

        let json = JSON(result)
        let profilePicture = json["picture"]["data"]["url"].stringValue

        if let url = NSURL(string: profilePicture) {
            if let pictureData = NSData(contentsOfURL: url){
                response = pictureData
            }
        }

    })
    print(response)
    return response
}
```

Comment: Of Course it will be nil. because at the time the method reaches the return statement. the photo has not been downloaded fully. you cannot return it. your method should not have a return type. instead you should use protocols. It's odd that it print it!

Comment: @OmarAl-Shammary use delegation or a completion handler, not a protocol.

Comment: @RMenke Yes I meant delegation actually. thanks. although completion handler might be a better option.

Comment: sorry I'm still trying to get to grips with swift, I need to pass the photo to other view controllers in my application so can you suggest how I could use a delegation? Or a completion handler? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Facebook call is using an async completionblock and your return statement will return *nil* before the call is done loading. That is why you also should use a completion block in your method.

Here is an example how to do this:

```
    func getProfilePicture(completion: (pictureData: NSData?, error: NSError?) -> Void) {

    let graphRequest : FBSDKGraphRequest = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: ["fields":"picture.type(large)"])
    graphRequest.startWithCompletionHandler({ (connection, result, error) -> Void in

        var pictureData: NSData?

        let json = JSON(result)
        let profilePicture = json["picture"]["data"]["url"].stringValue

        if let url = NSURL(string: profilePicture) {
            pictureData = NSData(contentsOfURL: url)
        }

        completion(pictureData: pictureData, error: error)
    })
}
```

You can call this code like this:

```
        self.getProfilePicture {(pictureData, error) -> Void in

        if error != nil {
            print("login error: \(error!.localizedDescription)")
        }

        print(pictureData)
    }
```